# How to Copy the Environment Variables from Sysinternal's Process Explorer

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, process-explorer

Is there an elegant way to copy the Environment Variables to clipboard of a Process from Process Explorer?
I was trying to compare two C++ compiled processes, and want to see how the environment variables differ. It seems I cannot copy the Text and subsequently paste it to compare visually.

**Note** I would rather want to stick with PE rather than juggling with multiple tools, but if using another tool is the only option please feel free to suggest.

Also tagging it as C++, expecting a solution from a C++ developer's/debuggers  point of view including using Visual C++

Comment: May be more simple way is using win32 api in your program ( GetEnvironmentStrings function)

Comment: @KostiaShiian: I understand I can read the User process parameter of any process from PEB, but actually I was looking for a Tool for debugging purpose.

Comment: How about this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25647/Read-Environment-Strings-of-Remote-Process ? I dont remember but may be there is tool in Support Tools or Resource Kit and also Windows Debugging Tools may help you.

Comment: @KostiaShiian: Yes, that's the closest I got too and was experimenting with it now. Just need to ascertain if the result can be trusted. I am yet to go through the source :-)

Comment: windbg !peb command display it

Comment: @sergmat: Yes, I completely forgot about it. Please post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windbg `!peb` command displays it.

Comment: Both yours and @MSalters solution makes sense. But I still feel PE should allow to copy the data to clipboard.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone still interested, version 16.02 of process explorer now has the ability to copy the properties of a process the same way as process hacker does.  I don't know when this ability was added.

Comment: Works great now! No context menu. Just use Ctrl+C

Answer (score 5):

Sysinternals Process Explorer can't do this at the moment. Very annoying and surely a bug, especially if a variable's value is too long to be displayed.

The open source tool Process Hacker 2 (http://processhacker.sourceforge.net) does not have this problem. Usage is similar to Process Explorer:

1. Launch [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)
2. Double click the process of interest
3. Click the "Environment" tab
4. Select All (Ctrl+A), then Copy (Ctrl+C)

Comment: Process hacker was just what I needed.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! You saved my day. I had dozens of entries in my path environment variable and an install of CLISP on windows nuked all of them and added only the path to CLISP!

Answer (score 1):

Just check the `_environ` variable in the debugger.